# Simplifying trick for extremizing functionals

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

If I have a functional $I[y] = \int{({y^\prime}^2- 1)^2}dx$ , since $f(x) = x^2$ is an increasing function for $ x > 0$, can I make the conclusion that $I[y]$ is extremized for at the same functions that extremise the functional

$J[y] = \int{({y^\prime}^2 - 1)}dx$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is altogether a different function,
If the action is defined as 
$$I=\int L(y,y',x) \mathrm dx$$

this extremizes when $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}=0$$

So for the case where another action is defined  as

$$J=\int [L(y,y',x)]^n \mathrm dx$$

gives 
 $$\frac{\partial L^n}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L^n}{\partial y'}=0$$

So this of-course doesnt give the same equations as before